# Azure AD and Azure AD B2C using same JWT token

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, hybrid, azure-ad-b2b

I have a scenario where the users are created in AZ AD B2C(It is an external facing application where users can be from different organizations as well as any individual). The application does this via jwt token from AZ ADB2C. The application also has embedded Power BI report which does not support AD B2C authentication. Is there a possibility to use the same jwt token to validate a user against AZ AD account as well?

Please let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: In that case you should use client credentials flow to get report data where your application will be working as client and will have its own app registered in azure ad.

Comment: The current behavior is : user authenticates from AZ AD B2C, then when clicks on "Reports" tab, it basically asks user to sign back again but this time authenticating against AZ AD(B2B). This is not a good user experience and that is where the solution I am looking for if this can be seamless.

Comment: That's why I suggest, when user click on Reports tab, just call your API endpoint that is secured Azure B2C Token, inside that endpoint, use Client Credentials flow to invoke other REST API using C#. Once you get the data in C#, just pass it to client from user endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general no.

Azure AD and B2C have two different key sets so the signature will be different.
As will the clientID, audience and issuer.